# Changed video card, x11 not loading

Tags: 14.04, xorg

I've changed video card and my Ubuntu 14.04 stopped loading.
After some googling, I've localized the problem - X11.
I believe, I have to at least delete the information about old video card or somehow re init X?

I can load to the tty1 or the root session in recovery, but dont know where to find that info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, Ill leave it here, maybe someone will find this useful:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

To check if succeded:

```
startx
```